# Windows Server DNS Issue - Apple iOS fails with Server2008 r2

Tags: windows-server-2008, internal-dns, ios, ipad

We have a peculiar issue in that our company ipads cannot resolve DNS correctly when pointing to server 2008 r2 with the DNS role. They are however, resolving correctly when targeting server 2012 with the DNS role.

We are trying to deploy numerous ipads across the field in the hope that we can use the Apple Server MDM solution for management.

Any advice / help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks Aaron

Comment: Can you make sure what the dhcp server gave to the ipad ? To be sure all dns suffix was correct. (apple call dns suffix 'search domain' by the way)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. The search domain is indeed correct. The difficulty we have with changing any DHCP server settings is that we have 80+ stores and thus 80+ routers to configure with our ISP. thanks

Comment: What is the version of dns.exe?

Comment: working server 2012 is 6.2.9200 and both server08 r2 are running 6.1.7601. thanks

Comment: So... Replace the server running 2008 R2?  Probably a good idea for other reasons, as well.

Comment: @AaronLyons:  I meant the full version of dns.exe, including the build number, which would be something like 6.1.7601.23251 if you had the latest DNS hotfix. Also, what does "resolving incorrectly" mean?  Is it getting a response but an incorrect address? Server failure?